# Multi Level Navigation Tree Using ListView to ListView Selection

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, navigation

I've searched other questions on the site and cant find a clear answer so I thought Id ask directly. I apologise if you feel there is repetition somewhere else.

I'm developing an app with 3 or 4 levels of navigation through List Views within Fragments under a Navigation Drawer Activity. In essence the development is going well but I need to avoid creating so many classes to handle each list Item to new list View transaction.

I guess I need to construct a master Array which will hold Arrays to populate the new List Views upon item selected. Ultimately, I need the list View templates to be populated by the correct information whatever is selected through the 3 or so levels until the final item detail is displayed.

How do I construct the arrays I need for the project(these are just text arrays until the detail page)?

```
<string-array name="All Arrays"> (syntax for this is unknown to me)
   <item>Array 1</item>
   <item>Array 2</item>
   <item>etc etc</item>
```

How to I call on each Array to populate a new list on Item Selection down through the navigation levels?

```
Array 1 selected from list - 
     populate list 2 from Array 1. ->   
then 
Array 1, Sub List 1 selected - 
     populate list 3 from Array 1, Sub List 1
then 
Array 1, Sub List 1, item 1 selected - populate detail page with item image         + text.
```

I would like to be aware of the most efficient way of achieving this without unnecessary repetition in code and XML. If possible and if you can help me achieve it I will be very grateful.

Thank you, Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use menu

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@+id/file"
         android:title="@string/file" >
         <!-- "file" submenu -->
         <menu>
              <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
              android:title="@string/create_new" />
             <item android:id="@+id/open"
              android:title="@string/open" />
        </menu>
     </item>
  </menu>
```

sample here
   https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/menu/drawer_view.xml

Comment: Menu is being used by the navigation drawer and this further navigation is conducted within the fragments. Does this cause an issue with using menu again?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to make this suitable for displaying lists in seperate fragments.